# Licensing options for libre game built with MonoGame (Ms-PL)

Tags: copyleft, ms-pl

I want to release a game built with the MonoGame framework, which includes the Ms-PL in its [license](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/LICENSE.txt). I want to include source code with my game and impose a strict requirement for others who modify or redistribute it so they're required to provide source code as well.

However, based on [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/4174/17423) and gnu.org's website, the GPL is not compatible with Ms-PL. Since my game is built with MonoGame (DLL included next to executable), does this count as "distributing" the library? Given these conditions, is there any license I can use that will allow me to impose a strict source code requirement to ensure my game remains libre?

Note that this won't cover my game assets (music, sounds, textures, etc), only the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Since my game is built with MonoGame (DLL included next to executable), does this count as "distributing" the library?

Yes. If people download the MonoGame DLL together with your executable (possibly in the same installer package), that definitely counts as distributing the library.

> Given these conditions, is there any license I can use that will allow me to impose a strict source code requirement to ensure my game remains libre?

You can choose a copyleft license that doesn't try to extend itself to the MonoGame library. An example of such a license is the [MPL-2.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/), which has copyleft terms for the code which is put under that license by you, but not for third-party code. The MPL-2.0 is effectively a per-file copyleft license.